# bash While script not echo correctly

Tags: bash, while-loop, echo

I have a text file /tmp/tmpGetFilefile-only.
In the Text File it has the following  (there is no blank line between the values)

goce

gocetengoce

When I run the below script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
  do
  echo "File: ${line}"
done < /tmp/tmpGetFilefile-only
```

I get this. As you can see the echo command is not working.  Why is this so ?

./whileshh.sh

```
goce:
gocetengoce
```

Comment: Your file has crlf newlines, fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: You can also get `read` to remove the carriage return with `while IFS=$'\r' read -r line`

Comment: Your input lines have a carriage return somewhere (probably at the start of each line). You can verify this by looking at the file with a hex editor, or by doing a `xxd /tmp/tmpGetFilefile-only`. If you get weird output, always check your input for weird characters in it! And when you are asking such a question here on Stackoverflow, include the hexdump of your file. The file is small enough that showing a hexdump is reasonable.

Comment: @Barmar : THIS output would IMHO be better explained by a CR at the start of `$line`.